# How to send the extension of the file too via code in laravel to the gcloud app storage bucket?

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

Am storing my pictures in gcloud app storage bucket via coding in laravel it's working.

But I want to save them with the same name as I saved them in the DB with their extension, so  I can retrieve them easily.

The image is saving in the GCS bucket with the name automatically created by them and without extension.

Here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
        $photo = $request->image->storeAs('ufurnitures-img', $imageName, 'public');
    }

    // Save the data into GCS
    $extension = $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $storage = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => 'ufurnitures'
    ]);

    $bucket = $storage->bucket('ufurnitures-img');
    $bucket->upload(
        //fopen($request->image.'.'.$extension, 'r')  //This one is not working
        fopen($request->image, 'r')   //This one is working
    );

    // Save the data into database
    Product::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'image' => $photo
    ]);
    $request->session()->flash('msg','Your product has been added');
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [options when you upload your blob](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.135.0/storage/bucket?method=upload).

```
    $options = [
        'name' => '/path/to/file.extension',
    ];
    $bucket->upload(
        //fopen($request->image.'.'.$extension, 'r')  //This one is not working
        fopen($request->image, 'r'),   //This one is working
        $options
    );
```

Comment: You can mark the answer as valid to allow other users to trust it!

Comment: Ops my bad! 
I thought I did that. :P
Done now :)
Thanks again ^_^